# set base class for roslyn script project

Tags: c#, scripting, roslyn

So i have a compiler class that i use to run user code. Now my problem is that my documents are scripting documents and i dont know how to set the base class for this documents. i was looking for 
hostObjectType but i saw that the isSubmission must be true, but i cant do that because the rest of my code will break.

Code to initialize the compiler:

```
public static async Task Init(Type host, params Assembly[] assemblies)
{
  await Task.Run(() =>
  {
    IsInitialized = true;
    workspace = new AdhocWorkspace();

    var compilationOptions = new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary, allowUnsafe: true, usings: new string[] { "CCreative" }, platform: Platform.X64)
      .WithMetadataImportOptions(MetadataImportOptions.All);

    var scriptProjectInfo = ProjectInfo.Create(ProjectId.CreateNewId(), VersionStamp.Create(), "Script", "Script", LanguageNames.CSharp, isSubmission: false, hostObjectType: host)
                                       .WithMetadataReferences(assemblies.Select(x => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(x.Location, default, x.Location.Contains("CCreative") ? new CCreativeDocumentationProvider() : null)))
                                       .WithCompilationOptions(compilationOptions);

    project = workspace.AddProject(scriptProjectInfo);
    workspace.TryApplyChanges(project.Solution.WithOptions(GetOptions(workspace)));
  });
}
```

so my goal is to set the base class of all the scripting documents to the host parameter.

Code to create a document:

```
public static DocumentId AddDocument(string text)
{
  var scriptDocumentInfo = DocumentInfo.Create(DocumentId.CreateNewId(project.Id),
                                               "Script",
                                               sourceCodeKind: SourceCodeKind.Script,
                                               loader: TextLoader.From(TextAndVersion.Create(SourceText.From(text), VersionStamp.Create())));

  var scriptDocument = workspace.AddDocument(scriptDocumentInfo);

  project = scriptDocument.Project;
  workspace.TryApplyChanges(project.Solution);

  return scriptDocument.Id;
}
```

Any help will be welcome :)